# Sylius v 1.0.6 Is it possible to filter by attributes

Tags: symfony, sylius

In the version of Sylius 0.18 was the ability to filter products by attributes. Everything worked. When upgrading to version 1.0.6, the filter does not work. Has the concept changed? In the demo version of the site, too, filtering by options and attributes of products is not implemented. The question is more to the developers.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: @vogan if you need filtering by taxons, not by attributes I can share you with the gist

Comment: In the documentation for filtering by attributes, there is only a link to GridBundle

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, filtering by taxons has already been implemented

Answer (score 0):

You can use elastic search or install Sylius plugin: https://sylius.com/plugins/